# Installing Rails on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, osx-mountain-lion

I was wondering if you could help me find why I cannot install Ruby on Rails on my MBP with OS X Mountain Lion. It's a weird problem and I'll give you as much info as I can.

I've installed ruby and it's working at version 1.9.3


And I've installed ruby gems and it's worked for every other gem I've tried to install.
It's version is 1.8.24

When I run `$ sudo gem install rails` it replies with the message: `Successfully installed rails-3.2.8
1 gem installed`

Although when I ask it `rails -v` it returns:

```
`Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.`
```

What should I do? 

The rails bash file (`/usr/bin/rails`) contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# Stub rails command to load rails from Gems or print an error if not installed.
require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"
if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
version = $1
    ARGV.shift
end

begin
    gem 'railties', version or raise
rescue Exception
    puts 'Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:'
    puts
    puts '    $ sudo gem install rails'
    puts
    puts 'You can then rerun your "rails" command.'
    exit 0
end

load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

That must mean that the gem files aren't there or are old or corrupted
How can I check that?

Comment: I also meet this problem! What is the update?

Comment: I first used JewelryBox as the RVM, but failed to install Rails as your case. Then I found this [page](https://www.wheelhousecms.com/blog/2012/7/installing-ruby-rails-and-mongodb-on-mountain-lion) and followed the instructions, now every thing works.

Comment: I didn't get it to work I reimaged my computer then restarted the whole process and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a fresh install of Mountain Lion...

I tried using,

```
sudo gem install rails
```

...straight out of the box.  This gave errors summarised by,

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

However, this same command succeeded after I installed the Xcode command line tools via,

```
Xcode 4.5.2 -> Preferences -> Download -> Components
```

I made no other changes other than installing the command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using this [resource to install rails](http://railsinstaller.org) and everything you need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Railsinstaller released a installer for OSX, try to download their installer from the git repository https://github.com/railsinstaller (seems that someone broke their official webpage).

Comment: You two have the same software you're recommending and it didd't work

Answer (score 0):

I installed Mountain Lion on my Macbook the other day. I used [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install RVM (and followed the post-install instructions!), then used RVM to install the latest version of Ruby (1.9.3). From there I set 1.9.3 as the default and then ran `gem install rails`. So far it has ran without a hitch!